# Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a function that looks through a number of matches from an array and find all teams in matches, that meet some conditions. When found they need to be assigned to a new array. The new array should be used as an output parameter.

I get `segmentation fault: 11` when I call it. I have tried to debug but cannot seem to get why. Following is declared in main:

```
TEAM team_least_viewers;
double spectators = 99999;    
solve_task_four(round, team, &team_least_viewers, &spectators);
```

And the function itself:

```
void solve_task_four(ROUND *round, TEAM *team, TEAM *team_least_viewers, double *spectators) {
  int i, j, k = 0;

  for(i=0; i<ROUNDS_PR_SEASON; i++) { 
    for(j=0; j<MATCH_PR_ROUND; j++) {
      if(round[i].match[j].year == 2015) {
        /* Searching for team name in team[]*/
        for(k=0; k<NUMBER_OF_TEAMS; k++) {
          /* If it matches  */
          if (round[i].match[j].home_team == team[k].name) {
            team[k].spectators_home_last_year += round[i].match[j].spectators;
          }
        }
      }
    }
   for(k=0; k<NUMBER_OF_TEAMS; k++) {
     if(team[k].spectators_home_last_year < *spectators) {
        *spectators = team[k].spectators_home_last_year;
     }
   }
  }
}
```

The structs as requested:

```
typedef struct {
  char weekday[WEEKDAY_SIZE], start_time[START_TIME_SIZE], 
       home_team[TEAM_SIZE], away_team[TEAM_SIZE];
  double spectators;
  int day, month, year, round, home_team_score, away_team_score;
} MATCH;

typedef struct {
  MATCH match[MATCH_PR_ROUND];
} ROUND;

typedef struct {
  char *name;
  int points, matches_played, 
      matches_won, matches_draw, matches_lost, 
      matches_won_home, matches_won_away,
      goals_for, goals_against, goal_difference;
  double spectators_home_last_year;
} TEAM;
```

Any help is **much** appreciated.

Comment: `if(team[k].spectators_home_last_year < *spectators)` comparing doubles is not a good idea.

Comment: @hbagdi: Why would comparing doubles be a bad idea?

Comment: Can you post the TEAM, ROUND and MATCH structs?
Also, `round[i].match[j].home_team == team[k].name` cannot do a string comparisiong if that's what you wish to do here.

Comment: Where is the segmentation fault occurring?  How are `TEAM` and `ROUND` defined?  What data are in your arrays?

Comment: I would suggest you to use any debugger like gdb to know about the root cause in detail. That way you would learn a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I infer your questions is: How do I figure out what is causing the segmentation fault? If that's right, then one answer is to use a debugger. Another answer would be to add print statements throughout the code. The segfault is almost certainly one of the array indexings, like round[i] or round[i].match[j], so be sure to print the i and j values. You may be indexing past the end of an array or dereferencing a null pointer or an uninitialized pointer, so print the pointer values, like `printf("round[%d] at %p\n", i, &round[i])`.

Answer (score 1):

SIGSEGV on several operating systems is signal 11, and is delivered to the process on a segmentation fault.

Segmentation faults occur when your program accesses memory in a way which isn't allowed, usually by attempting to dereference a null pointer or running off the end of an array.

In your program, the most likely culprits are are array indexes, `round[i].match[j]` and `team[k]`. (Another possibility would be if the `spectator` argument passed were not a valid location for writing, but this is unlikely in this particular case.) You may wish to insert code/run in a debugger to check whether each access is correct.

In particular, assuming that your `ROUNDS_PR_SEASON` &c. values are correct, it seems most likely that some `round[i].match` contains a null, if your `round` array was not fully initialized.

Comment: Well while it's technically correct it doesn't explain why it occurs, which appears to be the question here.

Comment: @LudaOtaku I see, I misread the question as not understanding the error message rather than the error itself.